# Almost surely tag

Tags: discussion, tag-management

We have a [almost-everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/almost-everywhere) tag for [measure-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measure-theory).  *Do we need "almost-sure" tag for probability space?*  The later is a particular case of the former, but the later concerns a vast variety of topics in [probability-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory), such as [Hewitt–Savage zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law), etc,  that won't be seen in questions about [almost-everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/almost-everywhere) in chapters about [lebesgue-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lebesgue-measure) in [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) books.

Comment: I'm almost sure that adding an "almost sure" tag might be a bit too much.